# Nominalized adjectives or nominalized adjective phrases?

Tags: adjectives, syntactic-analysis, definite-articles, nominalizations

Numerous adjectives can be combined with *the*. Examples include *the poor*, *the limitless*, *the miraculous*, etc. Such constructions are semantically equivalent to nouns. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalized_adjective):

> A **nominalized adjective** is an adjective that has undergone nominalization, and is thus used as a noun. In the rich and *the poor*, the adjectives *rich* and *poor* function as nouns denoting people who are rich and poor respectively.

However, it appears that the definite article *the* can precede [adjective phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjective_phrase) as well as single adjectives:

> It was a mental hospital for **the criminally insane**.

> It has over the recent years become a playground of **the rich and famous**.

> As always, travel bans do not apply to **the rich, famous, or powerful**.

If I mistake not, all of these examples possess constructions structurally similar to *the poor* or *the limitless*. Therefore, the definite article is combined with the whole adjective phrase
(*criminally insane*/*rich and famous*/*rich, famous, or powerful*) rather than a single adjective. Consequently, I think they are nominalizations of adjective phrases rather than nominalizations of single adjectives.

Comment: "The rich" (i.e. _rich people_  and "the poor" (i.e. _poor people_) are best analysed as fused-head noun phrases. "Rich" and "poor" retain their word class (POS) as adjectives while combining the function of head with that of modifier.

Comment: They're obviously very closely related. It's easy to get sidetracked into arguing over mere terminology. When new analyses are put forward, it is essential that older terms be defined stipulatively, or that newer terms be defined and explained (as with CGEL's approach put forward by BillJ).

Comment: Yeah, English arthrous adjectives are limited to plural generic use: _the poor_ can only mean _(all) poor people_. In Spanish or German, or many other languages, however, equivalents of _the poor_ can mean _the poor (man/woman)_, or, in the plural, _the poor men/women_. Similarly  for other articles and demonstratives: _aquello flaco_, in Mexican Spanish, means 'that skinny guy', _dos chicos_ means 'two children('s tickets)', etc. For some reason, we only do plurals and generic universals using definite articles in the singular. Of course, English adjectives are tough to pluralize.

Comment: What's your question? There's nothing surprising about being able to use adjectival phrases in a similar way as simple adjectives.